# Saving JPA entity twice

Tags: java, jpa, clone

I am trying to save one JPA entity twice as I want to store parent and revisions of my articles.

When I create new Article, I actually want to create parent and a revision which is a duplicate of the parent. Something like:

```
Article parent = new Article();
Article revision = parent.clone();

em.persist(parent);
em.persist(revision);
```

But what actually happens is that I am getting following exception on the second call of persist:

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: 
     Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

How can I clone the Article so that I won't get such exceptions?

Comment: Can you show your `clone()` method? Maybe you should rewrite it, without specifying for the copied object the id of the initial one.

Comment: Is the primary key an auto generated or you are generating and setting it. If you generate it, then clone might have copied the id to the revision and that is causing an issue.

Comment: The key is autogenerated. I made sure it is not copied. Obviously the "clone" method copies some of HIbernate properties, which is not desired.

Answer (score 0):

Does your clone method copy the @Id (and possiblty the @Version), too? You really should give your copy a new ID (or if you are using @GeneratedValue, the unsaved value so a new value is generated).

Comment: Both parent and revisions have @GeneratedValue, so for both of them the value was generated automatically.